# GetBootstrap 3 Slider Bug

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a problem with GetBootstrap's classic, simple slider.

Open this page.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Click on left or right arrow. There's a hover and focus. When you hover or focus one of arrows, background will be darker. When you move mouse out of arrows, the background will go back to default. But...

If you click on arrow, then move mouse out of arrow, the arrow's hover class will remain.

Normally, if you move mouse out of arrow, it means you're not focusing arrow anymore and class for hover/focus should not be applied on arrows.

I am trying for a few days to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: The `:focus` styles are needed for keyboard accessibility. Please don't make it harder for disabled people to use your site.

Comment: Okay, I know that. How can I change that :focus definition to disappear when I move my mouse out of arrow?

Comment: The `:focus` pseudo-class selector is a built-in CSS concept, and you can't change when it applies. You'd have to either blur the elements using JS or move those styles into `:hover` instead, but like I said, both of those harm accessibility.

Comment: I know @cvrebert, but trust me, disabled people will not come to web site I am trying to make. I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

"If you click on arrow, then move mouse out of arrow, the arrow's hover class will remain." is not quite correct--it's the arrows **:focus** definition that remains. Click anywhere else and it disappears. (to note though, bootstrap defines the :hover and :focus states together).

You can remove the definition for :focus (although not the best practice)...

In bootstraps CSS file, you will find this:

```
.carousel-control:focus, .carousel-control:hover {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Change it to this:

```
.carousel-control:hover {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    outline: 0 none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: Yes, I did that. But it was changing the color of arrows in some blue. So, the fix for this is:

`.carousel-control:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  outline: 0 !important;
  opacity: .9;
}

.carousel-control:focus {
  color: white;
}`

Thank you guys.